# SQL. Find doctors' names who have all patients with age less than 30

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables Doctor, Patient, DoctorPatient. Doctor has fields ID,name,phone. Patient has fields ID,name,phone,age,sex. DoctorPatient contains the DoctorID and PatienId, that's the link between Doctor and Patient tables. How can i find doctors who have all patients with age less than 30?

There are relationships between tables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you group by the doctor, then the total patients have to be the same as the total patients under 30.

```
SELECT Doctor.name
, COUNT(IIF(Patient.age < 30, Patient.ID, null)) AS TotalPatientsUnder30
, COUNT(Patient.ID) AS TotalPatients
FROM Doctor 
JOIN DoctorPatient AS dopa ON dopa.DoctorID = Doctor.ID
JOIN Patient ON Patient.ID = dopa.PatientID
GROUP BY Doctor.ID, Doctor.name
HAVING COUNT(Patient.ID) = COUNT(IIF(Patient.age < 30, Patient.ID, null))
   AND COUNT(Patient.ID) > 0
```

Comment: There is my solution :                 SELECT x.Name
FROM Doctor AS x
WHERE x.DoctorID NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT DoctorPatient.DoctorID
FROM Patient INNER JOIN DoctorPatient ON Patient.ID = DoctorPatient.PatientID
WHERE Patient.age > 30
);

Comment: Negation should work. But it should then be `age >= 30`.  And it'll also return doctors without patients. Those also don't have any patients under 30.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

gives sql:

```
SELECT Doctors.DoctorName, Max(Patients.age) AS MaxOfage
FROM Patients INNER JOIN (Doctors INNER JOIN DoctorPatient ON Doctors.ID = DoctorPatient.DoctorID) ON Patients.ID = DoctorPatient.PatientID
GROUP BY Doctors.DoctorName
HAVING (((Max(Patients.age))<30));
```